# accessing images

Tags: php, symfony1

I am new to Symfony.

I created a layout page in which I have this :

```
<img  src="images/header.jpg" width="790" height="228" alt="" />
```

but the image isn't displayed in the page when accessed from the browser.

I put the file header.jpg in the web/images/ folder.

I thought I could learn Symfony in a week while working on a small project. is it possible ?

Comment: Is web the document root and is images readable by the webserver? Try to add a slash before images, e.g. /images

Comment: What do Firebug and the web server logs say?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I added it but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slash at the beginning like

```
<img  src="/images/header.jpg" width="790" height="228" alt="" />
```

You can also use image_tag (which is better for routing)

```
image_tag('/images/header.jpg', array('alt' => __("My image")))
```

In the array with parameters you can add all HTML attributes like width, height, alt etc.

P.S. IT's not easy to learn Symfony. You need much more time

Comment: I think Tom's got it here, are you trying to access the image from a dev controller?  If so, and your paths are set to relative URLs like you pasted above, then your browser is looking for the image at /app_dev.php/images/header.jpg.  Adding the forward slash to the beginning of the path makes it absolute and should fix your issue.  Also, you can use the image_tag function without specifying /images/, it's added by default and the function will automatically adjust to dev controllers: image_tag('header.jpg', array('alt' => __('My image')))

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a fully PHP generated image tag but just want the correct path to your image, you can do :

```
<img src="<?php echo image_path('header.jpg'); ?>"> width="700" height="228" alt="" />
```

Notice that the path passed to [image_path](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_2/AssetHelper#method_image_path) excludes the /images part as this is automatically determined and created for you by Symfony, all you need to supply is the path to the file relative to the image directory.

You can also get to your image directory a little more crudely using

```
sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir')."/images/path/to/your/image.jpg"
```

It should be noted that using [image_tag](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_2/AssetHelper#method_image_tag) has a much larger performance cost attached to it than using [image_path](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_2/AssetHelper#method_image_tag) as noted on [thirtyseven's blog](http://th1rty7.blogspot.com/2009/01/symfonys-imagetag-handle-with-care.html)

Hope that helps :)